# Get Earliest and Latest Date into single MySQLi result sorted by Earliest Date

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a website which publishes music concert information for different concert venues. Each concert performance has its own row in a database table. Therefore, a concert performed on three separate days at a venue has three row entries with different dates. There may also be another set of dates which relate to a different venue.

I am trying to retrieve MySQLi results for each concert name containing the Earliest and Latest Date for each for a specific venue. I need to order the result rows by the Earliest Date of each concert and also disregard past dates.

My Database has the following structure

```
Name    |   Venue   |   Date
---------------------------------------------
ConcertA|   A       |   2017-12-04
ConcertA|   A       |   2017-12-01
ConcertA|   B       |   2017-11-28
ConcertB|   A       |   2017-11-13
```

and I need to output the following

```
Name    |   Venue   |   EarliestDate    |   LatestDate
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
ConcertA|   A       |   2017-12-01      |   2017-12-04
ConcertB|   A       |   2017-11-13      |
```

Comment: [GROUP BY with MAX and MIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: select Name,Venue, min(Date) EarliestDate, max(Date) LatestDate
from table_name
group by Name,Venue
order by min(Date)

Comment: What if the concert is held on the 15th - 18th March, and then again on the 15th to 18th April?

Comment: I'm not too concerned with that as a problem. I just want to display the start and end date that a user can see a particular concert at a venue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Venue, min(Date) EarliestDate, max(Date) LatestDate
FROM {your-table-name-goes-here}
GROUP BY Venue
ORDER BY min(Date)
```

Comment: This worked with the addition of a Date limit to disregard past dates. Date >=CURDATE()

Comment: I'm using MySQLi prepared statements in a function and my results contain 'min(Date) EarliestDate' instead of 'EarliestDate'. Does anyone know of a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the select from Jonny

```
SELECT Venue, min(Date) as EarliestDate, max(Date) as LatestDate
```